# Multiple Grouping with IQueryable and returning a list of objects in C# linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table [ot_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbN7b.png) like in this link. I have to return a list of `ot_request` entity class with the following conditions.

1. I have to filter the list where the `status_id==5`
2. After the filtering, I have to group the rows by their `project_id`
3. After the grouping by `project_id`, there will be some `creator_id` which has same value. So within the `project_id` grouping, again I have to group those Items by their `creator_id` and sum the `worktime_hours` belongs to them.

I have tried the following Linq query:
(context is object of the DB Entities)

```
IQueryable<ot_request> filterList = context.ot_request
                                  .Where(o => o.status_id == 5)
                                  .GroupBy(o => o.project_id)
                                  .Select(o => new { Project = o.Key, 
                                          Total = o.Sum(v=>v.worktime_hours))})
                                  .OrderByDescending(o => o.Total);
```

but it showing me the error message :

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` to
>       `'System.Linq.IQueryable<Project.DataEntity.ot_request>'`. 
>       An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: In your Select you're creating a new anonymous type. That's why it says `System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<AnonymousType#1>`

Comment: Ask for yourself: what are the things you are ordering? Are they ot_requests? or are they something different, something with Project and Total? So if you are ordering this input, what do you expect as output? Can this be converted to a ot_requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing:

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Total);
```

to:

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Total).Select(z => z.Project);
```

*You are currently returning the anonymous type setup by your existing `Select` call, not the specific type you are interested in.*

Alternatively, if you are specifically interested in the `Total`, change:

```
IQueryable<ot_request> filterList
```

to:

```
var filterList
```

which will ensure that `filterList` is an `IQueryable` of your new anonymous type (including `Total`).